# Asymptotic relation between $n^2 (n-2\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)$ and $2\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

What is asymptotic relation between $n^2 (n-2\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor)$  and $2\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$?

My attempt: let $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor = n$. Then the equation comes down to $n^3 $ and $n$ in terms of order function. Therefore, $n^3 \in \Omega(n)$.

However, this is not correct.

Comment: Well, $n - 2 \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ is not of order $n$, so the first expression is not of order $n^3$.

Comment: The sequence on the left is $1^2, 0, 3^2, 0, 5^2, 0, 7^2, 0, \ldots$.